# DevOps : AWS Lambda .zip with Terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, azure-devops, terraform

I have written Terraform to create a Lambda function in AWS.
This includes specifying  my python code zipped.
Running from Command Line into my tech box, all goes well.
The terraform apply action sees my zip moved into AWS and used to create the lambda.

Key section of code :

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "meta_lambda" {
              filename = "get_resources.zip"
              source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("get_resources.zip")
              .....
```

Now, to get this into other environments, I have to push my Terraform via Azure DevOps.
However, when I try to build in DevOps, I get the following :

> Error: Error in function call   on main.tf line 140, in resource
>   "aws_lambda_function" "meta_lambda": 140:   source_code_hash =
>   filebase64sha256("get_resources.zip") Call to function
>   "filebase64sha256" failed: no file exists at get_resources.zip.

I have a feeling that I am missing a key concept here as I can see the .zip in the repo - so do not understand how it is not found by the build?

Any hints/clues as to what I am doing wrong, gratefully welcome.

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that the file is there before Terraform runs? Can you add a step that lists the directory or runs something like `tree` first?

Comment: ydaetskcoR, can you post as an answer and I'll apply the bounty (see my answer) as even if I found the solution by other means, I appreciate your input :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chaps, I'm afraid that I may have just been over my head here - new to terraform & DevOps !
I had a word with our (more) tech folks and they have sorted this.

> The reason I think yours if  failing is becuase the Tar Terraform step
>   needs to use a different command line so it gets the zip file included
>   into the artifacts.   tar -cvpf terraform.tar .terraform *.tf tfplan
>       tar --recursion -cvpf terraform.tar --exclude='*/.git' --exclude='.gitignore' .

.. it that means anything to you !
Whatever they did, it works !

As there is a bounty on this, I still going to assign it as I am grateful for the input !
Sorry if this was a it of a newbie error.

Answer (score 2):

You can try building your package with terraform AWS lambda build module. As it has been very useful for the process[Terraform Lambda build module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-lambda/tree/master/examples/build-package)

Answer (score 0):

According to the document example, in the `source_code_hash` argument, `filebase64sha256 ("get_resources.zip")` needs to be enclosed in double quotes.

[image]

You can refer to this [document](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html) for details.

Comment: Hugh, thanks for the tip. It seems this has changed in the latest vsn  :   Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated

  on main.tf line 141, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "meta_lambda":
 141:   source_code_hash = "${filebase64sha256("get_resources.zip")}"

Terraform 0.11 and earlier required all non-constant expressions to be
provided via interpolation syntax, but this pattern is now deprecated. To
silence this warning, remove the "${ sequence from the start and the }"
sequence from the end of this expression, leaving just the inner expression.

Comment: Agree with ydaetskcoR , you can list the directory to check if the zip file included before runs.